# adb is not recognized in command window?

Tags: android, netbeans, adb

I have installed keystore using this tutorial:
https://sites.google.com/site/furodet/bits-n-tips-n/compile-helloandroid-with-netbbeans

and follow these steps:
https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/procedure_for_android_development_on

at the last step when I type:

adb install helloworld-release.apk

an error appears:
adb is not recognized as an internal or external command

How to solve this problem?

EDIT

I am typing in command window

C:\Users\Student\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FirstAndroid\bin>adb install helloworld-release.apk

And that error appears.

So what is wrong?

Thanks

I am using Netbeans to create Android Application

Comment: you go to your installed folder in cmd and execute the command...

Comment: I have to go to the installed folder not the application folder?

Comment: no no..go to installed folder sdk/platform-tools folder..

Comment: change that to `C:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: I have changed that to what all have suggested and it solve that problem. Now I have another problem which is error: device not found  waiting for devices

Comment: is your device connected???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using ecllipse and the path on windows where I have adb is

> C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools

Go to a similar location in your dev machine and try adb command again.

Comment: Thank you this solved that problem. But now I have another problem which is device not found

Comment: try running the emulator then. setting up device is a pain in windows you need device driver software. If you cannot find one try using universal adb driver as a last resort. Also newer kitkat version ask for rsa verification to user. And dont forget to enable developer options and usb debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try to download the driver and I hope it works.

Comment: dont mention it why not use ecllipse it is full fledged

Comment: Because I have started Java using NetBeans and I have got familiar with interface. But I will start using ecllipse if I still have problems with Android applications